# Collapse column inside another

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to collapse a column inside of another?

When I shrink the screen size to a smaller width, is there any possible way to have my `<img>` in "column-7" go underneath the "block-1" `<div>`?

I am aware I can push and pull columns in bootstrap, but I do not think that will work for what I am trying to achieve.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <div class="block-1">
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
        <h1>WORLD</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="block-2">
        <h1>GOODBYE</h1>
        <h1>WORLD</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <img src="//via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you think push and pull won't work? Seems like that's exactly what you need

Comment: Push and pull only changes order of columns. It does not enable me to put it inside another column. I am just trying to have my img or the column-7 go underneath "block-1" without having to have duplicate html to show and hide with media queries

Comment: Oh I see. You want it to go between hello world and goodbye world.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Will probably need javascript or a 2nd copy of the div to hide/show

Comment: You can't make that work with just CSS having the the block be appended to other container.